# HTML anchor link as name and not id

Tags: html

is it possible to add skip to content to link to name and not for id?

```
<a id="skiptocontent" href="#main" class="">skip to main content</a>
<h1 name="main">Main</h1>
```

Comment: you want to set `skiptocontent` to `name=""` attr?

Comment: i want skiptocontent to link to main. but i don't want to give the h1 id with "main"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There are some work-arounds:

#### 1. Add `id` property

Obviously, you could add the `id` property to the target element:

```
<h1 name="main" id="main">Main</h1>
```

#### 2. Add an anchor

If the target needs to be identified by name, add an anchor:

```
<a name="main"/><h1>Main</h1>
```

But in HTML5 the `name` attribute for the `a` element [is obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html).

#### 3. Use scripting to add the `id` attribute

You could add a script that will add the missing `id` attribute on page load:

```
<script>
    // find first element that has the name attribute set to "main":
    var element = document.querySelector('[name=main]');
    // copy that value into the id attribute
    element.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute('name')); 
</script>
```

You should then put this script block at the end of the document, so just before the closing `</body>` tag.

#### 4. Add script to the source link:

You could replace the `href` value with a script that will do the action based on the `name` attribute:

```
<a id="skiptocontent" 
   href="javascript:document.querySelector('[name=main]').scrollIntoView();" 
   class="">skip to main content</a>
```

#### Remark

As you tagged the question with HTML5, it should be noted that in HTML5 there is a clear moving away from using the `name` attribute as a target. `id` attributes are preferred in HTML5. That makes sense, because `name` values do not have to be unique, while `id` values have to be.